# Could you see this workflow in place for a development team within a digital agency?

Tags: jira, project-management-style, development-process

We are trying to figure out a workflow that our developers/PMs can follow 
 that gives a developer everything they need for a project. A step by step process that PMs and devs follow so that a) the project runs smoothly and b) developers get everything they need to complete a project.

We start by building our projects via the front-end team first and then it gets integrated further down the line. Whether that's a Wordpress/Open source CMS site, web application or larger more enterprise level CMS it all follows the same workflow. Again any input on this way of working would be helpful.

The process needs to be detailed and efficient but not so detailed and lengthy that it becomes inefficient. Could you see the below working within an agency:

- PM to supply project brief and design PDF/JPGS
- Dev to read through project brief and report back any queries to PM
- If dev accepts/assigned to project then create slack channel and add
  to team
- PM to supply PSD files
- Dev to review PSD files - Suggest amends (if any) and report back to PM
- PM to book in with Designer and get amended
- Add dev to Bitbucket repo and JIRA kanban board
- PM to supply bitbucket access
- Kick off meeting/hangout
- Sprint planning - divide project into sub-tasks
- Assign each task to relevant people and plan accordingly
- Put time estimate against each task to fill up the 8 hour daily limit
- Developer to development on static version. Commit code to repo each night
- Daily standup 15 minutes at 9am to review the previous and next day
  task/progress
- Dev to move task into JIRA ‘In Progress’ column when actively working on task
- Once task is complete move to ‘UAT’ column and assign to the PM
- PM to review task and assign back to dev if any amends/changes are
  required. Repeat until approved.
- Browserstack review in modern browsers and devices. Use browser check list. Add any findings or queries to relevant tickets/tasks within JIRA. If no tickets apply then create BUG and attach screengrabs. Notify via slack too.
- All code must be W3C validated. PM to check at https://validator.w3.org
  Report back any warnings/errors to relevant tickets/tasks within JIRA. If no tickets apply then create BUG and attach screengrabs. Notify via slack too.
- PM to review work with client
- Talk through any feedback with dev. Define a list of actions and then add to relevant tickets in JIRA. Also, find out whether amends are within project scope.
- Once all signed off developer can start CMS integration

Comment: Hello, welcome to PMSE. As your question stands, it's too specific and would add low to no value to the community, so without rephrase it's likely to be closed. Could you please work to make it more generic and focused on problems instead of solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow should be as simple as possible, that means it cannot have as many statuses as items on your list, also will help the process to run smoother.
While I cannot design the workflow for you I can give you some tips:

- Statuses represent something that already happened, more specific an activity that one person or team finished, ie: "reviewed with client, estimated, developed".
- Transitions are the actions that take you from one status to other, after you did what needed to be done in your current status, ie: "send to review, send to development".
- Most transitions will have associated information of why the issue transitioned, or information required in the next status.

Comment: I see - that makes more sense. What I have come up with sounds more like list of all 3 that could be simplified. Although the workflow does need to be very rigid to ensure process is followed to the T there are no clear states. 

This needs to be like a step by step instruction manual. I will amend and put into a flow diagram.